# PDF printing bug in OS X

Tags: macos, ms-office, pdf, printing, bug

On a PDF created with Office for Windows, special characters are not displaying and not printing correctly in OS X. The rendering is correct on Chrome.

The issue is the same as this one: [Some PDFs created by MS Word 2007's Save-as-PDF feature (on Windows) don't display correctly on Mac OS / iOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2894/some-pdfs-created-by-ms-word-2007s-save-as-pdf-feature-on-windows-dont-displ)

The file (created on Windows with PDF Distiller): https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8n7S6EXzIaJVXhOaFZncGZSdHc

The file (extracted from a document using print-to-PDF): https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8n7S6EXzIaJMkpxWHdCeEl2a0U

How can I resolve this?

Comment: So: is this a fault with OS X (not displaying a valid PDF) or with Office for Windows (creating a non-standard PDF)?

Comment: I agree that the document should be more standard but I can't ask the person who has created the document to rebuild it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/52294/pdf-rendering-bug-in-os-x-and-ios

Answer (score 1):

This issue now appears to be resolved; previewing documents on ML 10.8.2 now show the PDF's rendered correctly.

I'm not overly sure when this was resolved (it may well be something that was fixed in 10.8.0), but it looks like Apple has implemented a work around for the bad font embedding from Word generated PDF's

[image]

The updated PDf you posted is as shown, and works fine under ML.  I've included the URL bar to show it's the right file.

[image]

Comment: Oops, this one work for me either. I remember now that I've extracted the document with pdf-distiller under windows. I've receated the document at home under osX. Could you try open it ?

Comment: Works fine, answer updated.